# SQL Server Creating Unique clustered index on a column that has special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, special-characters, collation

Please pardon my SQL skills here but all am trying to do is to create a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` on a table that has data in it and that can't be dropped.

So my statement looks like --

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EmailRecord_AccountCode] 
    ON [GC].[Records] ([AccountCode], [EmailAddress]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Simple enough, pretty sure there are no duplicates in the table. But SSMS moans about duplicates, upon investigation I found out that there are 2 email addresses like

```
xxxx.xxxx@yyyy.co.uk 
xxxx.xxxx��@yyyy.co.uk
```

These 2 email addresses are different in the source data and there are two special characters like shown, my question is while SQL Server tries to create an index on this column why is it ignoring the special characters and considering it as repeated record and of course what is the way around it?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem if the column is declared `nvarchar()`.

Comment: but the char values are different? why is nvarchar forcing server to believe they are same ? though you are right column is nvarchar

Comment: The easiest way is to not make your index `UNIQUE`, or to fix your data. An alternative is to make the index on a computed column that uses a binary collation (`EmailAddress_BIN = EmailAddress COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2`). However, that index will be useless for actually searching on `EmailAddress`, since it's not indexing that -- you must search on `EmailAddress_BIN` (and then other "equal" addresses will not be found, obviously).  Changing the collation of the existing column is also an option -- that requires some dancing around with adding a new column, updating and renaming things.

Comment: As an aside, unless `EmailAddress` is never going to be updated, it's not a good candidate for a clustered index (the key as a whole will also be big, bloating other indexes and foreign keys). Consider if you really want to make that  the *clustered* index, or just a non-clustered index on a table that clusters on an identity.

Comment: How did you identify these two e-mail addresses as the problem? Since AccountCode is the leading column in the key, I suspect maybe there is a different duplicate causing the problem.

Comment: surprisingly when i did a groupby on accountcode and emailaddres having count *  > 2, i got these two rows returned